# Error in sed command

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed

input:

```
43572154    ROR2
43439911    LOC785925
42737842    LOC785930
```

expected output

```
'43572154':'ROR2'
'43439911':'LOC785925'
'42737842':'LOC785930'
```

Commands used

```
sed s/\n/\'\,\n\'/ input #substitute newline with ',\n'
sed s/ /\'\:\'/ input  #substitute <space> with ':'
```

But there seems to be no effect on the input. Can anyone please point out my error? Thnx

Comment: There are no commas in expected output, why are you trying to insert them?

Comment: why not awk? `cat input|awk '{print \'$1\':\'$2\'}'` or similar would do just as well.

Comment: What does your `sed` statement look like when quoted, or are you using a file? For example if you run `sed s/ /\'\:\'/ input` directly you get `sed: -e expression #1, char 2: unterminated `s' command` as an error.

Comment: @MarcB You don't even need cat for that, awk takes an optional second+ argument for the file to treat as standard input.

Comment: @MarcB You can't put single quotes in single quotes in the shell. Use double quotes and escape the dollar signs (and don't escape the single quotes).

Comment: i am trying to use on a file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the awk solution based on the comments:

```
awk "{print \"'\" \$1 \"':'\" \$2 \"'\"}" input
```

Answer (score 2):

Why do you try to replace newlines? Try this instead:

```
sed "s/\([^ ]\+\) \+\(.*\)/'\1':'\2'/" input
```

**EDIT** -- or with extended regular expressions (`-r`):

```
sed -r "s/([^ ]+) +(.*)/'\1':'\2'/" input
```

Comment: You should always use extended regular expressions to avoid all the backslashes. Basic regular expressions are essentially deprecated.

Comment: You don't need them here. `sed "s/.*/'&'";s/ /' '/" input`

Comment: @triplee You need `\+` if you want to replace multiple spaces (but, yes, you wouldn't if you know there are always 4). I find two substitution commands however harder to read.